# Check if something is before character php

Tags: php, string, replace

I would like to check whether there is some character before hyphen (-).

If there is something then add
 `<br>-`

If there is only space, do nothing.
I am not good with regexes :(

Comment: show us the bad regex that you have

Comment: You need to add to the question what, if anything, you have tried.

Comment: $newstr = preg_replace('/-\./s', '<br>-', "This is one line- this will be second");

This is what I tried but I think something has to be before hyphen in regex

Comment: *some character* - also numbers? or alphabetical only ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to be bad with regex at the beginning of my coding career, but just take the time to study it.

The pattern you are looking for is very simple: `([^\s])(-)`

Here you can test with it: http://regexr.com/3f73e

`[^\s]` means to match any characters that isn't a whitespace (`\s` means whitespace).

`-` matches the hyphen

`()` means a capture group.  So capture group one will capture the character before the hyphen and capture group two will capture the hyphen.  This is important for replacements as you want to maintain capture group one.

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `preg_replace` function and specific regex pattern:

```
$str = "The couch said: 'Use one-two-three combination'. -a) But it wasn't about boxing, it was about ping-pong";
$new_str = preg_replace("/(?<=\S)-/", "<br>-", $str);

print_r($new_str);
```

The output(as *view-source* code):

```
The couch said: 'Use one<br>-two<br>-three combination'. -a) But it wasn't about boxing, it was about ping<br>-pong
```

---

`\S` - points to non-whitespace character

`(?<=\S)` - positive *lookbehind* assetion, assures that a hyphen is preceded by a character